# Backtesting: choosing the "sample split" between in-sample and out-of-sample data

Tags: time-series, market-data, statistics, backtesting, historical-data

**Aims:**

- Given approximately 11 years of historical time-series data, to determine how much of this data should be reserved for `in-sample` and `out-of-sample` testing when using the data in the `backtesting` of a forecasting system
- To become familiar with potential techniques, if any, that can be used to determine an `in-sample` and `out-of-sample` split to reduce the likelihood of the `over-fitting` modelling error

**Details:**

As observable from the chart seen below, the time-series data spans from March 2012 to October 2023. During this approximate 11.5 year period, various market states/ conditions can be seen. For example:

- 2012 to 2014: up-trending market
- 2014 to 2016: down-trending market
- 2016 to 2018: sideways-moving market
- 2019 onward: substantial up-trend and highly volatile, then steep down-trend

Additionally, from the end of 2019, the data was likely sensitive to real-world inputs including the effects of the COVID-19 pandemic which were not present earlier on in the sample.

[image]

**Potential Approaches:**

- A simple 50:50 `in-sample` to `out-of-sample` split - the first half for testing and optimising, the second half for evaluating performance
- A `70:30` split so the system is built around the majority of the data before moving on to performance evaluation (this could be more susceptible to over-fitting)
- Given the various market conditions listed above, using a 50:50 split on each period i.e. the `bullish` market during 2012-2014 would be divided so the first half was for `in-sample` and the second half for `out-of-sample`. This process would be repeated for the bearish market from 2014-2016, the sideways market for 2016-2018, and the highly volatile and bullish market 2019 onward

**Questions:**

**Q1.** Based on the characteristics of the time-series data, are there any ways that this data could be divided or would a 50:50 split be sufficient?

**Q2.** Are there any techniques that would help in determining an appropriate sample split, or is this very much a discretionary process that is unique to each sample set?